# Getting Error while creating report through Report wizard. And Sql Database is on Godaddy's server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am Using **SQL Server Management 2012**. And connected to my online database which is on Godaddy's server. I Create an windows application in **c# and using visual studio 2012**.
Used  **string constring = "Data Source=184.168.47.21;Initial Catalog=ROT;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;";**
It works fine. Insert,update,delete all works fine. 
But now i am creating report. For that i used Report Wizard -> New database ->new dataset -> New Connection -> Servername=184.168.47.21 , clicked on Use SQL server authentication , write Username, password, write or select database name = ROT , clicked on test connection and got message Test connection Succeeded.
In Short I create two files Named "Report1.rdlc" and "ROTDataSet.xsd".
I designed report completely and take a **reportViewer1** for displaying Report1.rdlc.

** this.tbl_BookingTableAdapter.Fill(this.ROTDataSet.tbl_Booking,i);
                    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();**
above code is of button1_click event.And "i" is a integer parameter i am passing to it.

but when i click on this button it gives an error in file named "**ROTDataSet.Designer.cs**"
on line "**this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);**"
Error says  **"SqlException was unhandled. Login failed for user 'myusername'."**

Now Please tell me what i am doing wrong?
SqlConnection conn is working perfectly in application for select and insert query but it gives error in creating report. Even i can see my Table,Table adapter in .Xsd file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go daddy doesnt support SSRS on shared hosting http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6490/do-you-restrict-any-features-in-ms-sql-2008?isc=webxpa